# how to display name after login php in all other pages not only homepage

Tags: php

I'm having trouble to display my name in all the pages that I have after login in the website :

AuthentificationController.php

```
 public  function Connex($db,$login,$mdp)
 {

$requser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ? AND motdepasse 
 = ?");
$requser->execute(array($login,$mdp));
$userexist = $requser->rowCount();
if($userexist == 1)
{
$userinfo = $requser->fetch();
$_SESSION['login'] = $userinfo['login'];
$_SESSION['motdepasse'] = $userinfo['motdepasse'];
if($userinfo['role']=="admin")
{
session_start();
header("Location:/ProjetWeb2A1 - Copie/account.php?id=".$_SESSION['login']);
}

else if($userinfo['role']=="client")
{
session_start();

header("Location:/ProjetWeb2A1 - Copie/accueil.php?id=".$_SESSION['login']);
}
}
```

Homepage.php

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="header-left">
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="account.php">Inscription</a></li>
                <li class="login">
                    <div id="loginContainer"><a id="loginButton"><span>Se Connecter</span></a>
                        <div id="loginBox" style="display: none;">                
                            <form id="loginForm"  method="POST" action="\ProjetWeb2A1 - Copie\controllers\Authentification_controller.php">
                                        <label>Login</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="login" id="email" >
                                        <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                                    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Connexion" name="xxl1">
                                    <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> <i>Rester Connecté</i></label>
                                <span><a href="#">Mot de passe oublié?</a></span>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

If someone could answer me what i need to do to change that Inscription and Se

Connecter with my username in all my other pages please

Comment: Store the name in a `session` variable.

Comment: ...but don't store passwords in session variables; there is a "middle man" out there, just waiting.

Comment: You're also using unsafe code; don't wait till you get hacked. This, in regards to plain text passwords.

Comment: Can u guys just show me please how i'am really new with Php and i'am not that Pro using it so if it's possible to show me how to do exactly or to change my code as u told me please :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this :

Add a php file (functions.php in this example) with this content

```
<?php
    function logged_in () {
        if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function redirect_to ($url) {
        header("Location: {$url}");
    }
?>
```

Then, in your Homepage.php, import the saved file and check if the user is connected like this

```
require_once("functions.php");
<div class="header-left">
      <?php if (logged_in() == false) { ?>
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="account.php">Inscription</a></li>
            <li class="login">
                <div id="loginContainer"><a id="loginButton"><span>Se Connecter</span></a>
                    <div id="loginBox" style="display: none;">                
                        <form id="loginForm"  method="POST" action="\ProjetWeb2A1 - Copie\controllers\Authentification_controller.php">
                                    <label>Login</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="login" id="email" >
                                    <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                                <input type="submit" id="login" value="Connexion" name="xxl1">
                                <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> <i>Rester Connecté</i></label>
                            <span><a href="#">Mot de passe oublié?</a></span>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php } else { $name = $_SESSION['name']; ?>
            <h1> Hello <?=$name?> </h1>
         <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

You should save the `$_SESSION['name']` in your AuthentificationController.php

Comment: i tried ur example and it did kinda worked but he didn't recognize the $_SESSION['name'] in the $name = $_SESSION['name'] but when i put it manually it worked the other Div is not displayed and it showed me Hello Slim do u know where is the probleme why he didn't know the second $_SESSION ?

Comment: in your AuthentificationController.php add under $_SESSION['login'] = $userinfo['login']; this line 
$_SESSION['name'] = $userinfo['name'];
the field 'name' should exist in your 'users' table

Comment: It's Donne :D thanks a lot guys for the help i apreciate that !

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use $_SESSION, and want to populate it, start each page with :

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $login = $_SESSION['login'];
 echo"Welcome $login";
 ?>
```

simple code example, only to give you a hint... then, do whatever you need : check it, secure it...

Comment: and as u said how can i put that Login with is my username instead of Se connecter and Inscription div i'am sure uve got what i mean ^^

Comment: as @Fred -ii mentionned it earlier, you have a very insecure code! Please read about prepared statement in order to switch to this before going any further, and coding outdated/wrong things... then, at the top of each page, check $_SESSION values, then, if user is not logged in, show "register/log-in" form, otherwise, do any stuff matching your needs...

Comment: so the Show action of the Form i do it with Javascript ?

Comment: i did add  what u told me @Fred -ii but he didn't know the $_SESSION['login']